# python how to convert unicodes with variation selectors into string and render it properly

Tags: python, unicode

In Python3, is there a way to properly convert unicodes like "0x9f8d0xe0100" and "0x9f8d0xe0101" into strings so that we can visualize the differences these variation selectors make?

The base ideography 0x9f8d is '龍' in CJK. By visualization I meant for maximum portability like in terminal, text files, etc. when proper fonts are used.

Thanks!

Comment: Python sends those codes to the output, correct? So Python does not need to "do" anything; it depends on what you are using to *view* the output (your terminal or plain text viewer).

Comment: I want to visualize it in Python actually, so some variants of '龍' for example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after. The python unicode string would be `"\u9f8d\U000e0100". Are you saying you have literally `"0x9f8d0xe0100"`? The problem with that string is that one doesn't know how long the hex conversion should be. Is that 3 characters `"\x9f8d"` `"\xe010"` `"0"`?

Comment: yes, I'm basically taking input strings like "0x9f8d0xe0100", and it's up to me to convert it into an actual glyph string similar to "龍". I don't think it's made up with 3 characters but only 2: "0xe0100" is the hex representation of variation selector 17.

Comment: Variation selector is just a combining code point. so you should just put two codepoints together. A glyph/grapheme cluster is often built with more then one codepoint. Variation selector is not different. And your font should be able to use such hints (together with the language). Please use `U+XXXX` notation: it is much more cleasrer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty odd string format, but if that is literally what you have you can use a regular expression to parse out the values.  If there is no delimiter between the codes the expression needs a negative lookahead to prevent reading "9f8d0" instead of "9f8d".

- Match "0x"
- Match one or more hexadecimal digits.
- Don't match a digit before an "x"

`re.sub` can take a function for a replacement.  In this case convert the string of hexadecimal digits from the regex match to an integer using base 16, then convert it to a Unicode code point.

```
import re
for text in ("0x9f8d0xe0100","0x9f8d0xe0101"):
    result = re.sub(r'0x([0-9a-f]+)(?!x)',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),text)
    print(ascii(result),result)
```

Output:

```
'\u9f8d\U000e0100' 龍
'\u9f8d\U000e0101' 龍
```

Comment: Thanks! I just learned that we could concatenate the base ideography and the variation selector in strings like this. Just one more question, why is this type of notation (0x????) not ideal? It's basically a hexadecimal string representation of the unicode, and we can look then up in the unicode table, e.g., https://unicodelookup.com/#0xE0101.

Comment: @galactica for parsing it would be better to have a space or some other delimiter between the numbers.  As I explained I had to use a negative lookahead to tell the difference between 0x9f8d0 and 0x9f8d.  Why not just use actual escape codes?  `print('\u9f8d\U000e0101')` will display correctly, or use `chr(n)` to print the character for any integer `n`.

Comment: I see, but we can assume any unicode should start with "0x", it's a clear pattern for delimitation. I agree it introduces complexity for regex. Thanks again for the explanations!

Comment: yeah, I cannot control the way how strings are represented, so I can only try to deal with the current notation.

Comment: @galactica If you're typing Unicode constants anyway, using a unicode escape requires no conversion. `'\u98fd'` is the Unicode character, `'0x98fd`' requires conversion.